# C# - Calculating time difference in minutes

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, date-difference

I have got the following code:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(60000);
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
```

and I would like to calculate the difference in minutes between start and end. How am I supposed to do it? For the example above, the result should be '1'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The result is not guaranteed to be 1. It might be 1, it might be greater. `Sleep` only guarantees that no work will be done for `n` milliseconds, not that work will resume in `n` milliseconds. Don't be surprised if your result is incorrect at times.

Comment: You should *not* use `DateTime.Now` to measure the performance of code.  Use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.  Please read [Five Common Daylight Saving Time Antipatterns of .NET Developers](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use the `Subtract` method and using `TotalMinutes`.

```
var result = end.Subtract(start).TotalMinutes;
```

If you need it without fractional minutes just cast it as an `int`.

```
var result = (int)end.Subtract(start).TotalMinutes;
```

Have a look at the MSDN for further information: [Substract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TotalMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's easier than I expected!

Comment: I wanted to ask, what's the difference between var and int in this example?

Comment: @PSawicki, I would go and check in MSDN rather asking it

Comment: @PSawicki `TotalMinutes` is a `double`, so that `var` would be `double`, too.

Comment: @PSawicki [var information](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)

Comment: You can also just use the `-` operator:  `result = end - start;` which is easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 7):

I think a more elegant way of doing it would be by using the Stopwatch-Class

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: It's not just about elegance.  This is the only correct way to measure elapsed time.

Answer (score 3):

Simply take the difference (and maybe round it if you want):

```
double preciseDifference = (end - start).TotalMinutes;
int differentMinutes = (int)preciseDifference;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

It represents a time interval and will give you the difference that you're looking for.

Here's an example.

```
TimeSpan span = end.Subtract ( start );

Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
```